# Why can't I use for in makefile on Windows?

Tags: for-loop, makefile

I have tried many times, but `make` tells me `n` shouldn't be there.

My simple makefile:

```
all:
    for n in $(ALL_FILES); do\
        echo $$n; \
    done
```

The error output:

> `n` shouldn't be there.

Update:

Thank you, guys! When I run it in linux, It's OK. I find the for-syntax is not supported by Windows!

Comment: @Ed Heal I saw you modification, It makes me so sad!

Comment: I find the problem, Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider the [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) function, but you can also use `for`, be sure that your `for` loop would run outside the Makefile (especially check the format of `$(ALL_FILES)` to be iterable):

#### Makefile

```
all:
    @for n in $(shell seq 1 5); do\
        echo $$n; \
    done
```

#### Example

```
$ make
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Why should you add @ before "for"? my environment is Windows

Comment: It was just to avoid echoing the command

Comment: If you are running on Windows, the commands you write must be valid Windows commands that you could run in the Windows shell `cmd.exe`. Here, the commands you try to run are valid UNIX commands for a bash shell. You can either write a FOR that is valid in windows or use something like cygwin (or use linux).

Comment: So your opinion is 'for' is not a function or keyword in makefile?

Comment: No it isn't, it's just a command that `make` will execute, so it must be valid. If your code works it means that windows accepts unix-style for-loops, otherwise check the link for the `foreach` function or also here: http://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Comment: I tried it on my vitualbox, it do works! This problem is caused by my environment. Thanks for your answer!